# .data() is returning undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, undefined

This is my code:

```
$.getJSON("link here", function (result) {
    $.each(result, function (i, value) {
        $('.usersOfGroupList').append($("<li id='userElement' data-userId='' ></li>").data('userIdFromGroups', value.Id).html(value.FirstName + " " + value.LastName));
        console.log($(".usersOfGroupList").data());
    });
});
```

The value in the data-method is storing the data correctly but when I try to log this value in my console I get the whole javascript-object when I just want the value of D. I've also tried with the key like this:

```
console.log($(".usersOfGroupList").data("userIdFromGroups"));
```

but that just gives me an

> undefined-error

Comment: You need to use `console.log($(".usersOfGroupList li").data("userIdFromGroups"));`

Answer (score 3):

`id` needs to be unique per element so remove `id` attribute from `li`.

Since you are adding data attribute to newly created `li` so you need to use `li` as selector and `:eq(index)` to get the correct `li` each time.

Do like below:-

```
console.log($(".usersOfGroupList li:eq("+i+")").data('userIdFromGroups'));
```

***Sample hardcoded snippet:-***

```js
result = [{'Id':1,'FirstName':'A','LastName':'B'},{'Id':2,'FirstName':'C','LastName':'D'}];


$.each(result, function (i, value) {
  $('.usersOfGroupList').append($("<li data-userId='' ></li>").data('userIdFromGroups', value.Id).html(value.FirstName + " " + value.LastName));
  console.log($(".usersOfGroupList li:eq("+i+")").data('userIdFromGroups'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="usersOfGroupList">
```

***So full code needs to be:-***

```
$.getJSON("link here", function (result) {
    $.each(result, function (i, value) {
        $('.usersOfGroupList').append($("<li data-userId='' ></li>").data('userIdFromGroups', value.Id).html(value.FirstName + " " + value.LastName));// remove repetitive id
        console.log($(".usersOfGroupList li:eq("+i+")").data('userIdFromGroups')); // use index i to get correct li data
    });
});
```

Comment: Your answer is good, but the fact you removed `id=userElement` from your answer doesn't mean the op necessarily notices or understands what was done wrong. Also you ignored the asynchronous features of his request which might as well be the problem. If your answer does get chosen, please fill up the void.

Comment: @fingeron  for giving an example I did that, as I don't know what `link` he is using to get data as well as if he provided also I can't run here.

Comment: In my honest opinion it's not about giving a working example but rather making the op understand where he went wrong and how to make it work himself

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're giving the data to a newly created `<li>` under `.usersOfGroupList`, so you'll have to use the following to properly obtain it

`$("#userElement").data("userIdFromGroups")`

Also, in the above code it seems you're creating multiple elements with similar ids, which is very bad practice. Theoretically if there's only one `<li>`, it will work.

If it doesn't, that means you have some bad handling of asynchronous actions.

Since you're using an asynchronous function to obtain the data, and only then setting the data attributes on the desired elements. In the meantime, your code continues to run and tries retrieving the (yet unset) data property.